# Is Old Kafka written in Scala and new Kafka written in Java?

Tags: apache-kafka

Is Kafka written in Scala in old versions?  And only Java is used in newer versions? (Old code written in Scala is not used anymore?) If yes, why the change?

Or are Scala and Java still used?  If so, why does Kafka use both?

(I'm not asking if I can write producer or consumer in Scala or Java. I know Kafka clients can be written with many languages.)

Comment: Current Kafka server is written in Scala. Clients are in Java. Some logic that is shared between the server and the clients have written in Java.

Comment: Kafka is open-source, you can review any version at https://github.com/apache/kafka/. As for the motivation for client rewrite, see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Client+Rewrite

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The core module and Kafka Streams Scala wrapper are currently still in Scala

Clients (as of ~0.9), Kafka Connect and main Streams API are in Java

> why does Kafka use both?

Typically because Scala has nicer functional APIs and object typing semantics that are more dificult to work with in (prior) Java versions.

You can review all the code here - https://github.com/apache/kafka